# Integral with sine, cosine, x, and square root

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am wondering if there is any hope this indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^4(x)}}dx$$

could be calculated analytically? It's actually a simplified version of a more complicated integral I'm dealing with. I've tried a number of substitutions, and integration by part only seems to make things worse. I also played with the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) treating $a$ or $b$ as a parameter, but to no avail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the integral is not defined in general, note that $x\sim_0 \sin x$, therefore the integral diverges at zero

Comment: For the antiderivative, beside the case $a=b$, very little hope, I guess.

Comment: Regarding the domain: yeah good point. I'll have to check the exact limits, it's a little complicated with all the substitutions I made previously.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, maybe there's a more complicated antiderivative containing special functions such as elliptic integrals? even that would help